# CakePHP Routing & HTML Helper Link Ambiguity

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink, routes, cakephp-2.0, ambiguity

I have a site that uses CakePHP 2.x.  There's a backend interface where actions use the standard Cake layouts and views, but several of the actions are also exposed to front end users as "dialogs" (same functionality, just a layout that can be put in iframe).

In `app/Config/router.php` I have added the following:

```
Router::connect('/dialog/:controller', array('action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/dialog/:controller/:action');
Router::connect('/dialog/:controller/:action/**');
```

This works appropriately, but the problem starts when trying to use the HTML helper's `link()` method.  If I try to create a link like:

```
$this->Html->link('edit account', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit'));
```

I get the following:

```
<a href="/dialog/users/edit">edit account</a>
```

When the link is within a dialog, this works great, but I don't want the non-dialog pages to link to the dialog.

**How can I control which of the two URLs is used in a particular page?**

Is there something I can call from within AppController once I know whether the page being rendered is a dialog or not, or even something in the call to `link()` that would allow me to override it.

I know there's the "prefix" option which would allow for URLs like `/user/dialog_edit` but I would like to maintain the `/dialog/users/edit` format if possible.  I also know I can hard code the URL vs. passing controller/action/id/etc in an array, and I don't anticipate pathing/model names changing, but I'd like to do this the idiomatic way for CakePHP, if possible.

Comment: A "plugin" parameter sent with the URL array to link() seems to allow me to specify the leading portion of the URL, but I can't seem to suppress the leading portion (specifically /dialog).  passing 'plugin' => false or 'plugin' => '' doesn't seem to have any effect.  This seems close, but I'm still at a loss.

Comment: Are there more routes we're not seeing?  Seems strange.

Comment: These are the only changes I've made.  Those 3 connect() calls are just before CakePlugin::routes().  I'm not sure if the order of connecting routes is the issue, or what.

Comment: Regardless of where the link is, am I right in saying that requests get routed to the same controller and action?

Comment: Correct, /dialog/users/login and /users/login are executed the same way, only the view is rendered differently.